# PostgreSQL: OFFSET 0 and 1 is not working

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I am facing a weird issue with PostgreSQL query. If I set `OFFSET 0` or `1` it shows **Waiting for the query to complete...** forever. As soon as I change `OFFSET 2` or any other value it works fine.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT
        m.id,
        l.uuid,
        m.displacement,
        m.total_displacement
FROM
        locations l
        INNER JOIN markers m ON l.id = m.location_id
WHERE
        l.uuid = 42901 AND l.type_name = 'ascending' 
ORDER BY m.id ASC 
LIMIT 100 OFFSET 1
```

EXPLAIN information for

`OFFSET 0`:

```
Limit  (cost=0.85..127003.79 rows=100 width=28)
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.85..215537958.57 rows=169711 width=28)
        Join Filter: (l.id = m.location_id)
        ->  Index Scan using markers_pkey on markers m  (cost=0.57..209234879.46 rows=420204720 width=24)
        ->  Materialize  (cost=0.28..8.30 rows=1 width=16)
              ->  Index Scan using locations_uuid_type_name_key on locations l  (cost=0.28..8.30 rows=1 width=16)
"                    Index Cond: ((uuid = '4294967296001'::bigint) AND ((type_name)::text = 'ascending'::text))"
```

`OFFSET 2`:

```
Limit  (cost=127821.43..127821.68 rows=100 width=28)
  ->  Sort  (cost=127821.43..128245.70 rows=169711 width=28)
        Sort Key: m.id
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.57..121310.95 rows=169711 width=28)
              ->  Seq Scan on locations l  (cost=0.00..124.14 rows=1 width=16)
"                    Filter: ((uuid = '4294967296001'::bigint) AND ((type_name)::text = 'ascending'::text))"
              ->  Index Scan using markers_location_id_idx on markers m  (cost=0.57..118770.45 rows=241636 width=24)
                    Index Cond: (location_id = l.id)
```

**OFFSET 0**  has very heavy top-level costs.
Nested Loop  **(cost=0.85..215537958.57**

Does anyone guess the issue?

Postgre version: PostgreSQL 13.7

Comment: What is the PG version? Do you see anything interesting in the logs? How many rows does it return when OFFSET=2? Are there any other transactions which might lock the table?

Comment: Get the `EXPLAIN` output for both queries and add it to the question.

Comment: What if you use `LIMIT 102 OFFSET 0`?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I have added the explain information.

Comment: Are you using an old PostgreSQL version?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I am using PostgreSQL 13.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostgreSQL believes that scanning `markers` in `id` order and joining `locations` rows until it has found enough results is a viable strategy if few rows are needed. Obviously the optimizer is wrong in this assumption.

I have no idea how to improve the optimizer's estimates here, but you can force PostgreSQL to avoid the slow query plan by changing the `ORDER BY` condition to

```
ORDER BY m.id + 0
```

so that PostgreSQL cannot use an index scan to support it. PostgreSQL can only use an index for `ORDER BY some_expression` if there is an index on `some_expression`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your suggestion works fine but I don't understand what happened if I change `ORDER BY m.id` to `ORDER BY m.id + 0`. If you could explain that would be great.

Comment: I have added another line of explanation.